# Collect items into brackets (current and all preceding groups)

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

(Sorry if the term "bracket" is confusing, I took it from "tax brackets" as translated from dutch).

How can I collect items into groups *and each preceding group* based on a property threshold?

Example:

```
Loan A, duration of 6 months
Loan B, duration of 10 months
Loan C, duration of 12 months
```

Result as `Map<Integer, List<Loan>>`:

```
6 -> {A, B, C}
10 -> {B, C}
12 -> {C}
```

Currently I'm going the LinkedHashMap route and then after collecting the items from stream, run through all groups to update them:

```
Map<Integer, List<Loan>> loansByDuration = loans.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Loan::getDuration, LinkedHashMap::new, toList()));

List<Loan> previousGroup = null;
for (List<Loan> currentGroup : loansByDuration.values()) {
    if (previousGroup != null) {
        currentGroup.addAll(previousGroup);
    }
    previousGroup = currentGroup;
}
```

So what I'm doing is every subsequent list-value in the map will have all previous loans plus the loans only relevant for respective duration-key. Similar to cumulative subtotals.

Can this be done with standard API or else something like a custom collector?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by `addAll` here? and why don't you just do the `addAll` part on empty initialised list?

Comment: if you can use guava, there is `RangeMap`

Comment: @Eugene, I do have access to guava. I'll take a look at it, but meanwhile feel free to provide an answer with Guava :)

Comment: @nullpointer, I don't understand how that would accomplish the same thing. What I'm doing is every subsequent list-value in the map will have all previous loans plus the loans only relevant for respective duration-key. So like cumulative subtotals.

Comment: @Eugene, RangeMap is marked as Beta/Unstable. Don't think it's a good idea to use that in my situation (enterprise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the use case is it necessary to work with a type like `Map<Integer, List<Loan>>`? Thus every list *will have all previous loans*. This means there would be redundant references to `Loan`.

Or is the use case to provide views on `loans` grouped by `duration`?
In such a case we can use an alternative approach: A view on the loans using `Stream` (based on Java 9+).

```
public class Loans {

    private final List<Loan> loans;

    public Loans(List<Loan> loans) {
        this.loans = loans.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Loan::getDuration))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public Stream<Loan> getUpTo(int duration) {
        return loans.stream().takeWhile(l -> l.getDuration() <= duration);
    }

}
```

Since we have a `List<Loan>` sorted by `duration` we can use `Stream.takeWhile` to get a `Stream` of the desired `Loan`s for a certain `duration`.

This works e.g. like that:

```
Loans loans = new Loans(List.of(new Loan("A", 6), new Loan("B", 10), new Loan("C", 12));
loans.getUpTo(1); // <empty>
loans.getUpTo(5); // <empty>
loans.getUpTo(6); // Loan("A", 6)
loans.getUpTo(10); // Loan("A", 6), new Loan("B", 10)
loans.getUpTo(11); // Loan("A", 6), new Loan("B", 10)
loans.getUpTo(12); // Loan("A", 6), new Loan("B", 10), Loan("C", 12)
loans.getUpTo(100); // Loan("A", 6), new Loan("B", 10), Loan("C", 12)
```

In case a `List<Loan>` should be needed, we can still `collect` the streamed elements `toList()`.

Answer (score 0):

The simples solution I can think of is something like this

```
class Bucket(int limit, List<Loan> elements)

List<Int> buckets = Arrays.asList(6, 10, 12); // The bucket that you want to put items into
buckets.stream.flatMap(bucketLimit -> {
    List<Loan> loans = loans.stream()
        .filter(l -> l.getDuration() <= bucket)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new Bucket(bucketLimit, loans);
})
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Bucket::limit, Bucket::loans))
```

There may be some syntax errors here but you should be able to do something like this.